# Rails Activerecord: Update where conditions... else create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I need to check multiple columns of a table to see if I find a match. If I find a match I need to "updateattributes" of the matching record with all of my form params... Else I need to add a new record with all of my form params.

```
if @somethingtoupdate = Model.where("column1 = ? and column2 = ?", params[:something][:column1], params[:something][:column2])
  if @somethingtoupdate = Model.update_attributes(params[:something])
      redirect_to somewhere_path, :notice => "The existing record was updated"
  else
    render "myformlocation"
  end
else
  @added = Model.new(params[:something])
  if @added.save
    redirect_to somewhere_path, :notice => "The new record was created"  
  else
    render "myformlocation"
  end
end
```

**Update**

```
@somethingtoupdate = Model.where("this_id = ? and that_id = ?", params[:something][:this_id], params[:something][:that_id])
 if ! @somethingtoupdate.empty?
  if @somethingtoupdate.update_attributes(params[:something])
      redirect_to some_path, :notice => "The existing record was updated"
  else
    render "myformlocation"
  end
else
  @added = Model.new(params[:something])
  if @added.save
    redirect_to some_path, :notice => "The new record was created"  
  else
    render "myformlocation"
  end
end
```

This is where I stand now thanks to @micahbf.

But, I am still getting an error on my "update_attributes" when there is a matching record.

Seems like this should work.... What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks @micahbf that got me part of the way there. I have updated the question with the latest code based on what you suggested in your answer but I am still getting an error on the update_attributes when it runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `where` does not return `nil` if it doesn't find anything, it returns an empty array, which is still truthy, so the block gets executed.

You can use `empty?` to check whether to run the block or not.

Note also that if it finds a match, the match will still be returned inside of an array (even if there was only one match). So you will have to do something like call `first` on the result to take the first returned model and update it.

So, the top might look like:

```
@somethingtoupdate = Model.where("column1 = ? and column2 = ?", params[:something][:column1], params[:something][:column2])
if ! @somethingtoupdate.empty?
  if @somethingtoupdate.first.update_attributes(params[:something])
      redirect_to some_path, :notice => "The existing record was updated"
  else
    render "myformlocation"
  end
else
  // do stuff if the query found no matches
end
```

Comment: Thanks! That really helped the logic block execute only when it should and I have updated my question with some new code based on what you did here but I am still getting an error of: undefined method `update_attributes' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x00000003717c78> when it hits that block of "update" code. Any other thoughts?

Comment: @DrewHarris it's still in an array, so you need to take it out. I updated my answer.

Comment: Beautiful! @micahbf I feel like an idiot! Works like a charm now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I think here is short method to find record and if found then update record and if record not found then create it.

```
@somethingtoupdate = Model.where("column1 = ? and column2 = ?", params[:something][:column1], params[:something][:column2]).first_or_initialize
@somethingtoupdate.update_attributes(params[:something])
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `Model.update_attributes(params[:something])` is not working (at least in Rails 3.2.12). It should be `@somethingtoupdate.update_attributes(params[:something])`.

Also, there is an existing method for this kind of purpose: first_or_create.

```
@somethingtoupdate = Model.where("column1 = ? and column2 = ?", params[:something][:column1], params[:something][:column2]).first_or_create
```

Comment: It doesn't appear that first_or_create will take all of the params for :something to do the creation/update whereas in this case I needed to check just two conditions and add or update several others based on these conditions. Unless there is something about the first_or_create method that I am missing...?